# Remove ANSI color codes from a text file using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that runs and outputs to a text file however the colour codes it uses are also included what i'd like to know is how to remove them from the file, ie

```
^[[38;1;32mHello^[[39m
^[[38;1;31mUser^[[39m
```

so I just want to be left with Hello and User

Comment: Related answer using python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: Duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped

Answer (score 23):

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[(([0-9]{1,2})?(;)?([0-9]{1,2})?)?[m,K,H,f,J]//g" file_name
```

this command removes the special characters and color codes from the file

these are some of ANSI codes:
    `ESC[#;#H or ESC[#;#f`  moves cursor to line #, column #
    `ESC[2J`                clear screen and home cursor
    `ESC[K`                 clear to end of line,

note in case of clear code there is neither number nor semicolon `;`

agree with below comment:
if the numbers are more than 2 digit kindly use this:

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[(([0-9]+)(;[0-9]+)*)?[m,K,H,f,J]//g" filename
```

Comment: there is no guarantee on the number of number parts in the code, those for setting colour can have upto 5 numbers without redundancy.  the codes for setting other features (eg linux consile bell frequency) can have more than 2 digits in a row.

Comment: agree with you Jasen :-)

Comment: The commas in `[m,K,H,f,J]` are superfluous, right?

Answer (score 11):

My solution:

```
... | sed $'s/\e\\[[0-9;:]*[a-zA-Z]//g'
```

The colon is there to support escapes for some old terminal types.

Comment: What's the leading "$" for?

Comment: Ah, it's for the '\e' to be interpolated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966312/how-does-the-leading-dollar-sign-affect-single-quotes-in-bash#11966402

Comment: bash supports c-like escaping with $'...'

Comment: Tested this successfully with: `echo $'\033'"[38;1;32mHello"$'\033'"[39m"` (from Jasen's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296667/remove-ansi-color-codes-from-a-text-file-using-bash#comment50315550_19597730) )

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve the issue?

```
$ echo "^[[38;1;32mHello^[[39m" | sed -e 's/\^\[\[[0-9;]\{2,\}m//g'
Hello
```

cheers!!

Comment: No, it doesn't, because `^[` represents the ASCII Escape character (Control-[, code 27).

Comment: @Armali: don't understand your point. According to the OP's requirement, it should work. Can you post an example where it doesn't work? Cheers!!

Comment: Yes... `TERM=xterm tput setf 1|sed -e 's/\^\[\[[0-9;]\{2,\}m//g'|hexdump -C`

Comment: I don't think that what the OP is after.

Comment: I think you mean `echo $'\033'"[38;1;32mHello"$'\033'"[39m" | sed -e 's/\^\[\[[0-9;]\{2,\}m//g'` (what you wrote can't be pasted successfully)  ,and no it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The [mostly voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30938702/8474894) did not work for me straight out of the box. It needed a small tweak.

> **HowTo**:
>
> - *Run the following in a bash shell or add the following code block to you existing list of aliases to be able to reuse the `decolor` alias in future.*

```bash
## Decolor ANSI Colored Output
# example: (see preview in VSCode editor)
# >>> cat <filepath> | decolor | code -
alias decolor.styles='sed -E "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})*)?[m,K,H,f,J]//gm"'
alias decolor.reset='sed -E "s/\x1B\([A-Z]{1}(\x1B\[[m,K,H,f,J])?//gm"'
alias decolor='decolor.styles | decolor.reset'
```

**Usage**:

```bash
cat coloredtext.txt | decolor
```

**Output**:

```bash
PRESENT: /somepath/somefile_a.csv
PRESENT: /somepath/somefile_b.csv
```

### Dummy Data

```bash
# File Name: coloredtext.txt
# [1m[32mPRESENT:(B[m [32m/somepath/somefile_a.csv(B[m
# [1m[32mPRESENT:(B[m [32m/somepath/somefile_b.csv(B[m
\x1B[1m\x1B[32mPRESENT:\x1B(B\x1B[m \x1B[32m/somepath/somefile_a.csv\x1B(B\x1B[m
\x1B[1m\x1B[32mPRESENT:\x1B(B\x1B[m \x1B[32m/somepath/somefile_b.csv\x1B(B\x1B[m
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Here is a more general answer to remove any valid CSI (Control Sequence Introducer) sequence:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF8 sed -E "s/\x1B\[[\x30-\x3F]*[\x20-\x20F]*[\x40-\x7E]//g"
```

### Explanation

The sed regex `\x1B\[[\x30-\x3F]*[\x20-\x20F]*[\x40-\x7E]` matches the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences) description of a CSI sequence:

- `\x1B\[`: starts with `ESC [`
- `[\x30-\x3F]*`: any number (including none) of "parameter bytes" in the range 0x30–0x3F (ASCII `0–9:;<=>?`)
- `[\x20-\x20F]*`: any number of "intermediate bytes" in the range 0x20–0x2F (ASCII space and `!"#$%&'()*+,-./`)
- `[\x40-\x7E]`: ends with a single "final byte" in the range 0x40–0x7E (ASCII `@A–Z[\]^_`a–z{|}~`)

Character sorting is locale-dependent. For example, if you use `en_US.UTF8` you will get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 47: Invalid range end
```

To avoid this, add `LC_ALL=C.UTF8` at the beginning of the command (this will change the value of `LC_ALL` only for the `sed` command, following commands are unaffected)

Comment: `sed -r` is nonstandard; it would be preferable to post a properly POSIX-portable solution instead, or as well.

Comment: Changed to `sed -E`, thanks

Comment: That's also nonstandard. There is no POSIX flag which enables ERE.

Comment: `-E` will be in next POSIX revision, see https://github.com/mirror/sed/commit/8b65e07904384b529a464c89f3739d2e7e4d5135