# List Gitlab runners by name only

Tags: bash, awk, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to get a list of only the names of gitlab runners.

So the output of `gitlab-runner list 2>&1` is:

```
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
default_runner                                      Executor=shell Token=251cda361f983e612b27381e2f73ad URL=http://10.6.20.230
test runner                                         Executor=shell Token=86ab70918fc87c8a8d3a57c21457fb URL=http://10.6.20.230
```

Note that the names of the runners can contain spaces in them.

So I've tried the following:

`gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | awk -F'Executor' '{if(NR>1)print $1}'` which gives me pretty much what I want (except with trailing spaces that I'll need to remove).

```
default_runner
test runner
```

However, if I change the field separator to `Executor=` in hopes of making it more explicit, it no longer works. It returns the entire line.

```
$ gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | awk -F'Executor=' '{if(NR>1)print $1}'
default_runner                                      Executor=shell Token=251cda361f983e612b27381e2f73ad URL=http://10.6.20.230
test runner                                         Executor=shell Token=86ab70918fc87c8a8d3a57c21457fb URL=http://10.6.20.230
```

I've tried escaping it with `Executor\=` to no avail. How can I include the equal sign in my split?

**Edit:**

It works if I take one of the lines and echo it into awk

```
$ echo "test runner                                         Executor=shell Token=86ab70918fc87c8a8d3a57c21457fb URL=http://10.6.20.230" | awk -F'Executor=' '{print $1}'
test runner
```

Another thing to note is that, for whatever reason, `gitlab-runner list` prints to stderr. That is why I redirect to stdout before I pipe to awk. Maybe I'm not redirecting properly? But that doesn't really make sense since awk picks it up without equal sign.

Comment: What version of `awk` do you use? Is it `gawk`, and is it prior to 4.1.2?

Comment: @randomir GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: Thanks to your edit, I think I found the problem. Check below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't split on `Executor=` when piping from the `gitlab-runner` command is **because `Executor=` string is not present**! At least not it that form - `gitlab-runner` adds some [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (`ESC[0;m` is used to reset all attributes):

```
$ gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | cat -A
default_runner                        ^[[0;m  Executor^[[0;m=shell Token=86ab70918fc87c...
#                                     ^^^^^^          ^^^^^^      <--  ANSI color codes
```

To prove it, try running:

```
$ gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | awk -F 'Executor\x1b\\[0;m=' '{print $1}'
default_runner
```

There's an [open proposal](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1950) to add an option to disable color output in `gitlab-runner`, but it has been opened for 10 months already, without much community support. Until they decide to add that option, if you wish, you can strip ANSI color codes, for example like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4533/232065) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30938702/404556).

---

Note that in both [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) and [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Command-Line-Field-Separator) `awk`, `-F` accepts an ERE expression. So, `Executor=` should work in general (nothing special about `=`). To deal with spaces, you can use `<space>*Executor=`:

```
$ cmd | awk -F ' *Executor=' 'NR>1 {print $1}' | cat -A
default_runner$
test runner$
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use `jq` and format the output as `json`:

```bash
gitlab-runner --log-format json list 2>&1 >/dev/null | \
  jq -r 'select(.msg|contains("runner-name")).Token'
```

In combination with `xargs`:

```bash
gitlab-runner --log-format json list 2>&1 >/dev/null | \
  jq -r 'select(.msg|contains("runner-name")).Token' | \
    xargs -i gitlab-runner unregister \
      --url https://... \
      --token '{}'
```