# How to Quote a psql statement using su -c an a bash script?

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I am trying the following statement in a bash script:

```
su -c  "psql -d myDB-c 'SELECT count(*) AS number, date_trunc('day'::text, users.registerdate) AS registerdate FROM users;'" postgres
```

The Problem is the `'day'` parameter which needs to be quoted, but inside the quotes it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be attempting to wrap single quotes inside single quotes, which of course you cannot do.  `'this'and'that'` parses into `'this'` followed by an unquoted `and` followed by `'that'`, not into a quoted string `this'and'that`.

The usual solution is to wrap single quotes in double quotes, or vice versa, so `"this'and'that"` or `'this"and"that'` if substituting double quotes inside the quoted string is acceptable; but here, you already have both, so you can't do that (straightforwardly).

Assuming `psql` can read commands from stdin, the simple workaround here is to use a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

```
su -c "psql -d myDB-c <<'____HERE' 
    SELECT count(*) AS number,
           date_trunc('day'::text, users.registerdate) AS registerdate
    FROM users;
____HERE" postgres
```

Comment: You could also use the "ANSI C" string syntax of Bash.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966312/how-the-leading-dollar-sign-affects-single-quotes-in-bash