# What does the `$'...` do in this curl command line?

Tags: bash, curl

Chrome has given me a curl command that I don't fully recognize.  What does the `$'{...}'` do in the following curl command? I know that the `--data-binary` is the switch to put that string in the body of the POST, but I'm trying to understand if `$'...` gets "expanded" or something.

```
curl 'http://localhost.example.com:8080/graphql' \
-H 'cookie: auth.token_key=zztopTuNQ61YYbHGJpfA00' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
--data-binary $'{"query":"query workPlanSearch($searchParameters: WorkPlanSearchParameters\u0021) { workPlanSearch( searchParameters: $searchParameters ) { workPlanId } }","variables":{"searchParameters":{"partNumbers":"000-662-7980-001"}},"operationName":"workPlanSearch"}'
```

Is it a curl thing or a bash thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is duplicated of [How does the leading dollar sign affect single quotes in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966312/how-does-the-leading-dollar-sign-affect-single-quotes-in-bash)

```
It causes escape sequences to be interpreted. < This is the accepted answer in the link
```

And yes, I believe this is a bashism, take a look:

```
cat sh_test
#!/bin/sh
echo $'{"name":"joao\npedro"}'

./sh_test
${"name":"joao
pedro"}
```

```
cat bash_test
#!/bin/bash
echo $'{"name":"joao\npedro"}'

$ ./bash_test
{"name":"joao
pedro"}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is used for disambiguation, in your case it means to pass

```
'{"query":"query workPlanSearch($searchParameters: WorkPlanSearchParameters\u0021) { workPlanSearch( searchParameters: $searchParameters ) { workPlanId } }","variables":{"searchParameters":{"partNumbers":"000-662-7980-001"}},"operationName":"workPlanSearch"}'
```

as argument

It can used be used for separating a `car` from text, for example: `${var}text` means the content of `var` and the string `text` while `$vartext` means the content of the variable `vartext`